# Excel, worksheet scrollbar size

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, scrolling

I have a problem with the vertical scrollbar on one of my worksheets. The worksheet contains ~20000 rows and the scrollbar is too big to use conveniently.

However when I click and drag it, it changes to the correct size (appropriate to the number of rows).

Does anyone have an idea what can be causing this weird behavior?

For reference, the workbook contains many worksheets and extensively uses VBA (so maybe it is something inside, but I checked whole project and looked at, I believe, every reference to this worksheet).

The problem also occurs also in the Excel 2010 and Excel 2007 except dragging doesn't always help.

Screens:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No answer, but maybe try [this](https://github.com/byronwall/bUTL/blob/master/src/code/Usability.bas#L820)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately it doesn't help. I believe that it is somehow connected to the sheet settings, not the VBA code.

Comment: Copy the data to a new workbook, see if it still happens